# Realm adding an object to a List

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-list

Ok so here is my problem :
I have 3 Views and ViewControllers.
[image: The flow of my app]

And 2 Realm Object classes

[image]
[image]

In my first View when You click the "Order" button, by pressing this a function is called to create a new object in my realm List
[image: func]

The `UITableView`at the bottom is the populated with the new entry.
Then when you select the entry that was just created this function is called and takes you to the next ViewController 
[image: func 2]

Then by pressing the "add Item" Button I will proceed to to the next Viewcontroller where You will be able to add to the `OrderItem` and set the `name` and `amount`.
But when I click the add button I want to be able to know in which ListObject I am just like in the segue from the first VC to the second to be able to  make this function work

[image]

So my question is how do I let my `AddAnotherViewController` know which `List<Object>` to save to.
I know my question is a bit scattered but please I need your help

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is by add `selectedList` property to `AddAnotherViewController` and set it in `prepareForSegue` as you did for the previous segue.